# Checking strings for Non Standard Characters

Tags: java, json, regex

I am trying to find all of the non-standard characters in a json file. However, I don't really know the regex syntax for the [Pattern.compile(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-) method well enough to specify what I want. Basically, I want it to return anything that isn't a letter, number, "[", "{", ":", "\"", ",", "_", "(", "-", ".", "\", "/"

I'm just looking to print out the lines with special characters.

Code looks like the below:

```
for (String line : lines) {

        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z_0-9 && [[]] && [{}]");
        Matcher m = regex.matcher(line);

        boolean check = m.find();

        if (check) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Would be interesting to begin from there on.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Besides, we couldn't give you solution with nebulous "etc" in the requirements, even if we wanted to *(which we don't)*. If you don't know regex well enough to write it yourself, now is a great time to learn.

Comment: You want a method that takes a string and return it stripped of anything that isn't a letter, number, etc... is it?

Comment: You know where to find the JavaDoc, which is quite good for the RegEx, so I think you can at least have a go. You can easily test your regular expression using several [freely available online tools](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html).

Comment: Pattern.compile takes a regex as a string. Which part are you confused with?

Comment: @MxyL I think the OP has little experience with *writing* a regex, especially with capturing groups. I can imagine that they seem quite complex when you just start using them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex you can try:

```
[^\p{L}\p{N}\[\]{}:",_().\\/-]
```

Some notes:

- `\p{L}` matches all unicode letters in all languages. Replace with `A-Za-z` if you are only concerned about English letters.
- Likewise, `\p{N}` matches all unicode numeric signs. Replace with `0-9` if you are only concerned about the digits in the Latin alphabet.
- `[`, `]`, and `\` need to be escaped by a preceding `\`, since they otherwise have special meaning within the regular expression itself.
- The same goes for `-`, but by placing it right at the end it doesn't need to be escaped.

Then in order to express this as a Java string constant, you need to worry about characters that have special meaning within Java string syntax: `"` and `\`. So all occurences of `"` and `\` in the regex have to be escaped in the Java code:

```
"[^\\p{L}\\p{N}\\[\\]{}:\",_().\\\\/-]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this regex is printing all of the strings.

Comment: The regex matches a character that is not a letter, number, etc, so it matches all of the strings because each of the strings contain a character that matches. Your question says print out the lines with special characters. Maybe you could clarify that?